# Simple scraping / data collecting with C# Selenium not working

Tags: c#, selenium

So im trying to collect some data with Selenium using C# and I am fairly new to it, atleast the collecting data part, what im trying to achieve is, when I press a button is collects some data and puts it in a textbox, simple as that, the only thing is when I run my code it doesnt collect anything

im using a label as a button

```
    private void label11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var getTopFive = new FirefoxDriver();
        getTopFive.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.rottentomatoes.com/top/bestofrt/top_100_action__adventure_movies/");

        foreach (var item in getTopFive.FindElements(By.TagName("a")))

            //this is where I left off

        {
            activeTextBox.Text = (item.GetAttribute("class"));

        }
```

I think I messed it with the FindElements & GetAttribute but im not sure

Comment: What exactly do you want to present in `activeTextBox`?

Comment: @Guy I would like to take the text from the website and add to the textbox, my goal was to make it so it shows the top 20 movie titles in there

Comment: @Guy Do you know what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the tag `<a>` will give you many elements that doesn't connected to the movies. You need to find unique identifier for them, like `[itemprop='url']`.

```
IList<IWebElement> movies = getTopFive.FindElements(By.CssSelector("[itemprop='url']"));
```

Will give you a list of all the movies. You can extract the movie name using `Text` property

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; ++i)
{
    activeTextBox.Text = movies[i].Text;
}
```

Comment: I will try this out! I can see that you know alot about this subject, this might be wrong to ask but do you happend to have Skype or something similar?

Comment: I think I understand, the issue im having though is understanding when and how to use the <br>
 "FindElements(By.CssSelector("[itemprop='url']"));" <br>
How would I know that itemprop='url is a CssSelector

Comment: Also! That code only displays the 20th video title on the website, I looked over the loop and I cant seem to find anything wrong with it

Comment: @VinnyGarcia You can see the options for locating elements in [By class](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html). If you are not looking by attribute that is specified in one of them you need to use either `CssSelector` or `XPath`.

Comment: @VinnyGarcia Only the last video is displayed because you override `activeTextBox.Text` each iteration. If you also display the `activeTextBox` each iteration you will see all of them.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining!